# Uploaded extension manually not showing extension menu on frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation

I am trying to install an extension of Custom Stock Status. I uploaded all the files to it relevant folders by following the installation step provided by the extension. Now the issue is that the extension menu is not showing inside `Stores > Configuration`.

Here are the steps I followed.

```
Step 1:

Please unzip the archive.

Step 2:

Disable cache at System -> Cache Management.

Step 3:

Unload the contents of the module package to the Magento root folder. This will not overwrite the existing Magento files, only the new contents will be added.
```

At the first time, I didn't disabled Cache, after looking into the documentation I disabled cache and tried again but the menu is still not showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Putty in your PC then try to access that with your hosting IP;

```
 1. Open your SSH or try with PUTTY
 2. run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 3. run php bin/magento indexer:reindex
 4. run php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: SSH access that I have is not working. Is there any other alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I have all these. It was working earlier but suddenly it stops working. I was getting an error of `Login Failed`, so recreate the access but that didn't work. I contacted the hosting provider and they didn't respond back and I need to install extension urgently. That's why I was asking for another alternative.

Comment: Sure. let me do this.

Comment: Please provide menu.xml resides in etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Thanks. reinstalling putty worked and the commands worked for me. Thanks a lot.